# Delete Selected Rows from ListView Control using Checkbox asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listview

I am using vb.net in my website. I want to know If I have Listview Control & I want to delete selected rows by checkbox? I know it can be done by using 'For Each but how to execute this I have no idea. pLease help me.

```
<asp:ListView ID="productsList" runat="server" DataKeyNames="">
                                        <LayoutTemplate>
                                            <table class="content-table products-table">
                                                <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="checkbox-part">
                                                <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkAll" />
                                            </td>

                                            <td>
                                                Image
                                            </td>

                                            <td class="product-title">
                                                Name
                                            </td>

                                            <td>
                                               Item Code
                                            </td>

                                            <td>
                                                Budget
                                            </td>

                                            <td>
                                                MOQ
                                            </td>

                                            <td>
                                                Status
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                                <div id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" style="">
                                                    <div runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
                                                </div>
                                            </table>
                                        </LayoutTemplate>

                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="checkbox-part">
                                                <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chk" />
                                            </td>

                                            <td>
                                                <img src='<%#"../../" + Eval("image") %>' runat="server" class="lil-thumbnail" />
                                            </td>

                                            <td class="product-title">
                                                <asp:Label ID="id" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                                                <asp:Label ID="productName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("product_name") %>'></asp:Label><br />
                                                <asp:hyperlink ID="Edit" runat="server" cssClass="editbtn icn" ToolTip="Edit Product" NavigateUrl='<%# "new-product.aspx?edit=edit" & "&" & "productID=" & Eval("ID") %>'></asp:hyperlink>

                                                <asp:LinkButton ID="Delete" runat="server" CssClass="deletebtn icn" CommandName="DeleteProduct" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID")%>' ToolTip="delete" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this Item?')" CausesValidation="false"></asp:LinkButton>

                                                <asp:HyperLink ID="view" NavigateUrl="#" runat="server" CssClass="viewbtn icn" ToolTip="View Product"></asp:HyperLink>
                                            </td>

                                            <td>
                                                <asp:Label ID="sku" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("sku") %>'></asp:Label>
                                            </td>

                                            <td>
                                                <asp:Label ID="price_range" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("price_range") %>'></asp:Label>
                                            </td>

                                            <td>
                                                <asp:Label ID="moq" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("moq") %>'></asp:Label>
                                            </td>

                                            <td>
                                                <asp:Label ID="status" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("status") %>'></asp:Label>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:ListView>
```

UPDATE

```
Protected Sub deleteMultiple()
        Dim checkedItems As String = String.Empty
        For Each item As ListViewItem In productsList.Items
            Dim chk As CheckBox = DirectCast(item.FindControl("chk"), CheckBox)
            If chk Is Nothing Then
                Continue For
            End If
            'if no checkbox found, continue to foreach loop
            If chk.Checked Then
                Dim hdnId As HiddenField = DirectCast(item.FindControl("hdnId"), HiddenField)
                checkedItems += hdnId.Value + ","
            End If
        Next

        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(checkedItems) Then
            'checkedItems has ID of checked items which you can use to delete from database
            Dim lbl As String
            lbl = checkedItems
            Try
                Dim con As New MySqlConnection
                Dim query As New MySqlCommand
                con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("conio").ConnectionString()
                query.Connection = con
                con.Open()
                query.CommandText = "DELETE FROM products WHERE ID = @ID"
                query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", lbl)
                query.ExecuteNonQuery()
                con.Close()
                Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl)
            Catch ex As Exception
                Response.Write(ex)
            End Try
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have checkboxes in List ?  Please elaborate bit more or post screenshot/code.

Comment: You wanna delete row on <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chk" /> check ? Wanna delete from database or just hide?

Comment: Want to delete from database

Comment: @Sami anything you can help with this?

Comment: Sorry but I am not fully cleared about what you after, as you have checkboxes and delete button as well. You want to first select checkboxes and on Delete button click, execute delete process OR just check the checkbox and delete that row ? Please clarify. Thanks

Comment: @Sami Yes. First will select rows with checkboxes & then on delete button click it will execute deletetion of rows. As same as we do in gmail.

Answer (score 0):

In your ListView use a hidden field to hold ID like

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnId" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("ID") %>' />
```

Add OnItemCommand like

```
 <asp:ListView ID="productsList" runat="server" OnItemCommand="productsList_ItemCommand" >
```

In code-behind

```
protected void productsList_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        string checkedItems = string.Empty;
        if (e.CommandName == "DeleteProduct")
        {
            foreach (ListViewItem item in productsList.Items) {
                CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)item.FindControl("chk");
                if (chk == null) continue; //if no checkbox found, continue to foreach loop

                if (chk.Checked) {
                    HiddenField hdnId = (HiddenField)item.FindControl("hdnId");
                    checkedItems += hdnId.Value + ",";
                }                    
            }
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(checkedItems))
        {
            //checkedItems has ID of checked items which you can use to delete from database
            lbl.Text = checkedItems;                
        }

    }
```

Hope this helps you !

Comment: Thanks for this. Though I want this in vb.net . But now I know the logical part so I will try to achieve in vb

Comment: Did it fix your problem ? I hope you did :)

Comment: Give me some time as my problem gets fixed I will upvote & accept the solution for sure..

Comment: I just converted this in vb. My delete button is not inside listview so I have use onClick method.. In my post I have mentioned my code which only gets one row if multiple selected because delete query gets structured like this DELETE FROM products WHERE ID = '123,432,654,'